# why the crawlspace vent is closed?

Tags: vent, ventilation, crawlspace

I just move to a home and noticed the previous owner closed quite a few crawlspace vent. It seems to be intentional. I am wondering why he choose to close most of the vents and leave some of them still open.

As my understanding, it's better to keep crawlspace ventilated.

So I am going to keep all of them open. Could there be any problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where are you located?  Typically this is a seasonal question, based on tempatures.

Comment: I am at Oregon which is rainy in winter and spring.

Comment: Frrezing temp have more to do with closing than rainy seasons.